# Why didn’t park-goers bump into the invisible HMS Bounty more often?

Tags: star-trek, the-voyage-home

**In *The Voyage Home*, why didn't park-goers bump into the cloaked Bird-of-Prey (also known as the "HMS Bounty") more often?**

It seemed to be a fairly active park in an urban area (San Francisco).  Shouldn't more joggers be colliding face-first into the landing struts?  You might imagine that frisbees and baseballs would have been bouncing off of the hull.  What about birds dropping out of the sky after banging their noggins on the invisible obstacle?

You would also think that a few incidents of walking into an invisible object would cause a stir of some kind.

Comment: I'm asking this as a separate question from http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80100/, thanks to encouragement from @Richard.

Comment: I imagine rain would be a spectacle.

Comment: I dont have the time to screen cap the movie right now, but... they DID run into the landing strut.

Comment: Could be the [Sunnydale effect](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17366/20221).  If YOU ran into an invisible wall in the park, would you risk being called crazy for telling people?  Maybe you would, but its plausible that some people wouldn't.

Comment: @Tritium21 : Indeed, I did remember that, and it was partly an inspiration for the question.  That's why I wrote "Shouldn't **more** joggers be colliding face-first..." as opposed to "Shouldn't joggers be colliding face-first..."  ;-)

Comment: The movie is about Kirk and Spock and Whales... Its not about joggers.  Showing it once is enough to get the point across.

Comment: @Tritium21 : That's not really my question.  I'm not worried about joggers any more than I am about frisbees, baseballs, or birds.  I'm wondering why the **presence** of a cloaked Bird-of-Prey in the middle of a San Francisco park for several days did not create larger problems for the Kirk and Spock and the whales.  "You would also think that a few incidents of walking into an invisible object would cause a stir of some kind." :-)

Comment: Obviously the Klingon cloak also functioned as a [perception filter](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PerceptionFilter).

Comment: I once read a crossover fanfic, where a stir of some kind did get caused.  And ten years later, a certain FBI agent came across the cold case and looked into the matter.  No link available, sorry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The crew spent **less than 48 hours in 1986**. Arrived near dawn, went to Cetecean Institute that same morning then Kirk had dinner with Dr. Gillian Taylor that same day. During dinner Gillian says the whales will be transported tomorrow noon during a press event.

> Voyage Home (the scene with the two garbage men **near dawn**)
>
> The onshore breeze came up. It blew away the diesel fumes and brought a marshy, low-tide smell from the sea. Soon it would disperse the mist. Javy liked working the early shift; even on foggy days **he liked dawn.** A few minutes ago, before sunrise, he and Ben had seen a shooting star, surprisingly distinct in the fog.

Golden gate park is **1.583 square miles (4.1 square kilometers)**. The **chances are slim** that anyone will run into invisible landing struts in the middle of a meadow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Conveniently there is **no canon date for the arrival of the HMS Bounty.** So the writers must have intended for viewers to **choose a month where park visitors are at the minimum,** which further reduces the chance of detection.

The [official novelization](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home_%28novel%29) also mentions that the garbage collectors were there on an **early monday morning. (A Monday would guarantee a lot less visitors to the park)**. Also supported by the two lonesome joggers during the Bounty departure

> Voyage Home
>
> **Monday mornings** were always worst as far as garbage was concerned. His heavy gloves scraping on the asphalt, Javy scooped up the loose trash and pitched it into the park garbage can. He and Ben were only supposed to empty the cans, but Javy hated seeing Golden Gate Park trashed after every weekend, so sometimes he broke the rules.

The novelization mentions Kirk looking at the newspaper dispenser but conveniently Kirk does not notice the date.

> Voyage Home (scene where Kirk is looking at the newspaper dispenser)
>
> "Dow Jones Bull Turns Bear." The first two he found completely incomprehensible. He assumed the third to be a report on genetic engineering, though he did not quite understand why Jones would want to change a bull into a bear.
>
> "Nuclear Arms Talks Stalled." That one he understood.
>
> "It's a miracle these people ever got out of the twentieth century," McCoy said.
>
> Jim waited for the headline to dissolve into a news story, but nothing happened. He wondered if the news machine were broken. Probably street machines were not as reliable now as they were in his own time. He looked for a way to key it to the subject he needed, but saw no controls. Perhaps it was more sophisticated than it looked and could be operated by voice...
>
> ...Newspapers? That was it. The antique novels he had read sometimes mentioned newspapers, but. never newspaper machines. They described young newspaper carriers running down the street crying "Extra!" Jim wondered how anyone kept up with the news here. These headlines must be hours old.

Actual Movie location: http://www.movie-locations.com/movies/s/Star_Trek_IV.html#.VMd8sS7SWow ‘Golden Gate Park’, though, where the crew parks the ‘Bird of Prey’, **is actually Will Rogers State Park,** 14253 Sunset Boulevard, Pacific Palisades in Los Angeles.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about the joggers during the Bounty departure edited and added :)

Comment: The image of the whole park from above suggests that most of it is covered in trees, and that open grassy areas make up a relatively small fraction of its area, which I think would increase the chances that people would be walking on them.

Comment: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Golden+Gate+Park/@37.769421,-122.486214,13z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x71be8b68ef3ba730 Google Maps should give a better idea of the scale and how many open areas there are (just switch to satellite view)

Comment: "Golden gate park is 1.583 square miles (4.1 square kilometers). The chances are slim that anyone will run into invisible landing struts in the middle of a meadow." Seeing how much of the park is trees then I would say that it would add to the chances if they park it in the middle of a meadow. Thats where people in parks hang out after all...

Answer (score 3):

I live in the area, and the ball fields are not heavily used outside of baseball season because the diamonds are off-limits for casual play to prevent damage. People sometimes walk dogs on the grass outside the diamonds, but most stay on the pathways. Other areas of the park are more popular for picnicking and such. If the weather is cold, it is possible to imagine the field being deserted long enough for the plot line to hold.