# Where exactly in Golden Gate Park did Sulu land the Bird-of-Prey in Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home?

Tags: star-trek

Is there a suitably large grassy area in Golden Gate Park where a cloaked Klingon Bird-of-Prey could land? I don't think there are any hints in the film.

Comment: I always wondered why didn't anyone bump into it in the several days they were there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: So did I: see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80140

Comment: @RobertF: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80140/ might already answer your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The film wasn't on location in the real Golden Gate Park but on the [polo field of the Will Rogers State Park.](https://maps.app.goo.gl/uQP8frvcjpKt5Mq27)

> ‘Golden Gate Park’, though, where the crew parks the ‘Bird of Prey’, is actually Will Rogers State Park, 14253 Sunset Boulevard, Pacific Palisades in Los Angeles. The park is the former estate of humorist Will Rogers in the Santa Monica mountains.
>
> <sub><sup>[Movie Locations: Star Trek IV](https://www.movie-locations.com/movies/s/Star-Trek-4-The-Voyage-Home.php)</sup></sub>

---

As to the specific location of the Bird of Prey, the [script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/tvh.txt) tells us that they're parked approximately 15km into the park, on an almost direct west bearing to the township of Sausalito, San Francisco where the Cetacean Institute is based.

> **KIRK:** *We'll stick together till we get orientated. Bearing to the whales?*
>
> **UHURA** (with tricorder) *283 degrees... 15.2 kilometers...*

Unfortunately, such a bearing would place them squarely in the Gulf of the Farralones.

[image]

Assuming she meant due north (bearing 0), that would still place them about five kilometres outside of the park.

Comment: Right - but staying in-universe I'm curious if there is a location in Golden Gate Park where Sulu could discretely land the ship without crashing into trees?

Comment: @RobertF - Have you tried google maps?

Comment: @Jeeped Good point - Looks like Bison Paddock or the Polo Field would be the two most likely spots (assuming they existed in 1986). Now we just need a consistent estimate of the size of a Klingon Bird-of-Prey: http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/bop-size.htm :-)

Comment: Excellent detective work! :-) Looks like this was a major oopsie in the script. Perhaps the scriptwriters got the bearing wrong but the distance of 15.2 km is correct (so swing your vector south)? However that still doesn't quite work, Golden Gate Park is only about 12 km from the northern-most part of Sausalito. If we place the Cetacean Institute on the other side of Richardson bay the distance may work, but of course the bearing is still off. Unless the definition of kilometers and compass bearing have changed in the 23rd century.

Comment: "Assuming she meant due north (bearing 0), that would still place them about five kilometres outside of the park." The area just south of the bridge is actually The Presidio, Golden Gate Park is about 7 blocks farther south.

Comment: Not that it makes a lot of difference but you need to subtract 180 degrees from 283 to get the back bearing.

Comment: heywaitaminute... The Cetacean Institute is for studying whales, right? Why _wouldn't_ it be in the middle of the gulf?

Comment: @FreeMan - [You're not wrong](https://media0.giphy.com/media/AANqYGD9LVsw8/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47mum8d08jivl1mheoy4haseaum3nnr0re36d0ke81&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g)

Comment: @Robertf would a bearing from a tricorder be a relative or absolute bearing?  If you take it to be relative to the direction she was facing at the time then you can make it whatever compass bearing you want